# Asterisk 11 match destination extension in macro

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

Long story short: Fanvil phones don't allow you to change microphone volume (that is too low).

I've created this custom macro, but cannot match the case the phone (exten 131) is receiving a call, it work only when it make a call:

```
[macro-fanvil]
exten => s,1,NoOp(catch: callerid: ${CALLERID(num)} - exten ${EXTEN}- ${CHANNEL})
;exten => _131,n,Goto(receive)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${EXTEN} = 131]?receive)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num)} = 131]?:iscalling)
exten => s,n(iscalling),NoOp(alzachiamante: ${CALLERID(num)} - ${CHANNEL})
exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(RX)=10)
exten => s,n,MacroExit
exten => s,n(receive),NoOp(alzaricevente: ${CALLERID(num)} - ${CHANNEL})
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(TX)=10)
exten => s,n,MacroExit
```

This is from console:

```
    -- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:1] NoOp("SIP/195-00000096", "macro-fanvil: callerid: 195 - exten s- SIP/195-00000096") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:2] GotoIf("SIP/195-00000096", "0?receive") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:3] GotoIf("SIP/195-00000096", "0?:iscalling") in new stack
    -- Goto (macro-fanvil,s,4)

 Executing [s@macro-fanvil:4] NoOp("SIP/195-00000096", "alzachiamante: 195 - SIP/195-00000096") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:5] Set("SIP/195-00000096", "VOLUME(RX)=10") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:6] MacroExit("SIP/195-00000096", "") in new stack
```

It seems that ${EXTEN} is always the one that is calling, how can I catch the event of the 131 is the destination of the call?

Comment: Macro app is deprecated. Use GoSub instead of it, you can put anything in GoSub as dest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see `${EXTEN}` inside a Macro is always `s`.
`-- Executing [s@macro-fanvil:1] NoOp("SIP/195-00000096", "macro-fanvil: callerid: 195 - exten s- SIP/195-00000096") in new stack`

You have to tell the Macro the `${EXTEN}` when you calling it.
This is normally done with...
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Macros
...at...
**Calling Macro with arguments**
...where the Argument from the calling Channel/Context is outputed in: `Verbose()`

Long story short: You have to change your Macro to check the Argument

```
[macro-fanvil]
exten => s,1,NoOp(catch: callerid: ${CALLERID(num)} - exten ${ARG1}- ${CHANNEL})
;exten => _131,n,Goto(receive)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${ARG1} = 131]?receive)
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${CALLERID(num)} = 131]?:iscalling)
exten => s,n(iscalling),NoOp(alzachiamante: ${CALLERID(num)} - ${CHANNEL})
exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(RX)=10)
exten => s,n,MacroExit
exten => s,n(receive),NoOp(alzaricevente: ${CALLERID(num)} - ${CHANNEL})
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(VOLUME(TX)=10)
exten => s,n,MacroExit
```

...and call it with Argument: `Macro(fanvil,s,1,(${EXTEN}))`